# How do i find a jungle temple in minecraft pocket edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have never found a jungle temple before so my Minecraft question is how do i find a jungle temple in those naughty naughty jungles?

Answer (score 1):

As of update 0.15.0, [Jungle Temples](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Jungle_Temple) can be found in Jungle Biomes:

> They can be found rarely in Jungle Biomes, often close to the Water.

Note that Jungle Temples may also spawn [partially underground](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Jungle_Temple#Trivia), so keep your eyes on the ground as well when searching for them.

I also found [this guide](https://allaboutmcpe.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/jungle-temples-getting-past-the-traps-and-getting-the-treasure-assembling-the-wither-guide-release-date/) for traversing Jungle Temples and avoiding their traps.

Answer (score 0):

Jungle temples are not implemented into MCPE. It is not there due to the fact that it requires pistons and sticky pistons for one part of the Jungle Temple but those aren't added yet, either. So for now, there are no Jungle Temples in MCPE, but it will arrive in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

Its time to answer this old question but it is added on update 0.15 and can be found on the Jungle. It is somehow rare on the jungle.

Here is the reference for the information so you can research more about it: http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Jungle_Temple